# Why my Drupal is intermittently slow? Stracing shows a lot of repeated sendto calls

Tags: php, performance, drupal

One of the Drupal sites I manage occasionally loads very slowly. If I strace PHP-FPM while this happens, I see a lot of `poll`/`recvfrom`/`sendto` system calls with what appears to be the same content:

```
[pid 27381] recvfrom(5, "\7\0\0\1\0\1\0\2\0\0\0", 24589, MSG_DONTWAIT, NULL, NULL) = 11
[pid 27381] sendto(5, "\207\2\0\0\3INSERT INTO menu_router\n   "..., 651, MSG_DONTWAIT, NULL, 0) = 651
[pid 27381] poll([{fd=5, events=POLLIN|POLLERR|POLLHUP}], 1, 1471228928) = 1 ([{fd=5, revents=POLLIN}])
[pid 27381] recvfrom(5, "\7\0\0\1\0\1\0\2\0\0\0", 24578, MSG_DONTWAIT, NULL, NULL) = 11
[pid 27381] sendto(5, "\\\2\0\0\3INSERT INTO menu_router\n   "..., 608, MSG_DONTWAIT, NULL, 0) = 608
[pid 27381] poll([{fd=5, events=POLLIN|POLLERR|POLLHUP}], 1, 1471228928) = 1 ([{fd=5, revents=POLLIN}])
[pid 27381] recvfrom(5, "\7\0\0\1\0\1\0\2\0\0\0", 24567, MSG_DONTWAIT, NULL, NULL) = 11
[pid 27381] sendto(5, "T\2\0\0\3INSERT INTO menu_router\n   "..., 600, MSG_DONTWAIT, NULL, 0) = 600
[pid 27381] poll([{fd=5, events=POLLIN|POLLERR|POLLHUP}], 1, 1471228928) = 1 ([{fd=5, revents=POLLIN}])
[pid 27381] recvfrom(5, "\7\0\0\1\0\1\0\2\0\0\0", 24556, MSG_DONTWAIT, NULL, NULL) = 11
[pid 27381] sendto(5, "2\2\0\0\3INSERT INTO menu_router\n   "..., 566, MSG_DONTWAIT, NULL, 0) = 566
[pid 27381] poll([{fd=5, events=POLLIN|POLLERR|POLLHUP}], 1, 1471228928) = 1 ([{fd=5, revents=POLLIN}])
[pid 27381] recvfrom(5, "\7\0\0\1\0\1\0\2\0\0\0", 24545, MSG_DONTWAIT, NULL, NULL) = 11
[pid 27381] sendto(5, "\37\2\0\0\3INSERT INTO menu_router\n   "..., 547, MSG_DONTWAIT, NULL, 0) = 547
[pid 27381] poll([{fd=5, events=POLLIN|POLLERR|POLLHUP}], 1, 1471228928) = 1 ([{fd=5, revents=POLLIN}])
[pid 27381] recvfrom(5, "\7\0\0\1\0\1\0\2\0\0\0", 24534, MSG_DONTWAIT, NULL, NULL) = 11
[pid 27381] sendto(5, "\r\2\0\0\3INSERT INTO menu_router\n   "..., 529, MSG_DONTWAIT, NULL, 0) = 529
[pid 27381] poll([{fd=5, events=POLLIN|POLLERR|POLLHUP}], 1, 1471228928) = 1 ([{fd=5, revents=POLLIN}])
[pid 27381] recvfrom(5, "\7\0\0\1\0\1\0\2\0\0\0", 24523, MSG_DONTWAIT, NULL, NULL) = 11
[pid 27381] sendto(5, "B\2\0\0\3INSERT INTO menu_router\n   "..., 582, MSG_DONTWAIT, NULL, 0) = 582
[pid 27381] poll([{fd=5, events=POLLIN|POLLERR|POLLHUP}], 1, 1471228928) = 1 ([{fd=5, revents=POLLIN}])
[pid 27381] recvfrom(5, "\7\0\0\1\0\1\0\2\0\0\0", 24512, MSG_DONTWAIT, NULL, NULL) = 11
[pid 27381] sendto(5, ":\2\0\0\3INSERT INTO menu_router\n   "..., 574, MSG_DONTWAIT, NULL, 0) = 574
[pid 27381] poll([{fd=5, events=POLLIN|POLLERR|POLLHUP}], 1, 1471228928) = 1 ([{fd=5, revents=POLLIN}])
[pid 27381] recvfrom(5, "\7\0\0\1\0\1\0\2\0\0\0", 24501, MSG_DONTWAIT, NULL, NULL) = 11
[pid 27381] sendto(5, "(\2\0\0\3INSERT INTO menu_router\n   "..., 556, MSG_DONTWAIT, NULL, 0) = 556
[pid 27381] poll([{fd=5, events=POLLIN|POLLERR|POLLHUP}], 1, 1471228928) = 1 ([{fd=5, revents=POLLIN}])
[pid 27381] recvfrom(5, "\7\0\0\1\0\1\0\2\0\0\0", 24490, MSG_DONTWAIT, NULL, NULL) = 11
[pid 27381] sendto(5, "4\2\0\0\3INSERT INTO menu_router\n   "..., 568, MSG_DONTWAIT, NULL, 0) = 568
[pid 27381] poll([{fd=5, events=POLLIN|POLLERR|POLLHUP}], 1, 1471228928) = 1 ([{fd=5, revents=POLLIN}])
[pid 27381] recvfrom(5, "\7\0\0\1\0\1\0\2\0\0\0", 24479, MSG_DONTWAIT, NULL, NULL) = 11
[pid 27381] sendto(5, "(\2\0\0\3INSERT INTO menu_router\n   "..., 556, MSG_DONTWAIT, NULL, 0) = 556
[pid 27381] poll([{fd=5, events=POLLIN|POLLERR|POLLHUP}], 1, 1471228928) = 1 ([{fd=5, revents=POLLIN}])
[pid 27381] recvfrom(5, "\7\0\0\1\0\1\0\2\0\0\0", 24468, MSG_DONTWAIT, NULL, NULL) = 11
[pid 27381] sendto(5, " \2\0\0\3INSERT INTO menu_router\n   "..., 548, MSG_DONTWAIT, NULL, 0) = 548
[pid 27381] poll([{fd=5, events=POLLIN|POLLERR|POLLHUP}], 1, 1471228928) = 1 ([{fd=5, revents=POLLIN}])
[pid 27381] recvfrom(5, "\7\0\0\1\0\1\0\2\0\0\0", 24457, MSG_DONTWAIT, NULL, NULL) = 11
[pid 27381] sendto(5, ",\2\0\0\3INSERT INTO menu_router\n   "..., 560, MSG_DONTWAIT, NULL, 0) = 560
[pid 27381] poll([{fd=5, events=POLLIN|POLLERR|POLLHUP}], 1, 1471228928) = 1 ([{fd=5, revents=POLLIN}])
[pid 27381] recvfrom(5, "\7\0\0\1\0\1\0\2\0\0\0", 24446, MSG_DONTWAIT, NULL, NULL) = 11
[pid 27381] sendto(5, "\30\2\0\0\3INSERT INTO menu_router\n   "..., 540, MSG_DONTWAIT, NULL, 0) = 540
[pid 27381] poll([{fd=5, events=POLLIN|POLLERR|POLLHUP}], 1, 1471228928) = 1 ([{fd=5, revents=POLLIN}])
[pid 27381] recvfrom(5, "\7\0\0\1\0\1\0\2\0\0\0", 24435, MSG_DONTWAIT, NULL, NULL) = 11
[pid 27381] sendto(5, "6\2\0\0\3INSERT INTO menu_router\n   "..., 570, MSG_DONTWAIT, NULL, 0) = 570
[pid 27381] poll([{fd=5, events=POLLIN|POLLERR|POLLHUP}], 1, 1471228928) = 1 ([{fd=5, revents=POLLIN}])
[pid 27381] recvfrom(5, "\7\0\0\1\0\1\0\2\0\0\0", 24424, MSG_DONTWAIT, NULL, NULL) = 11
[pid 27381] sendto(5, "\253\2\0\0\3INSERT INTO menu_router\n   "..., 687, MSG_DONTWAIT, NULL, 0) = 687
[pid 27381] poll([{fd=5, events=POLLIN|POLLERR|POLLHUP}], 1, 1471228928) = 1 ([{fd=5, revents=POLLIN}])
[pid 27381] recvfrom(5, "\7\0\0\1\0\1\0\2\0\0\0", 24413, MSG_DONTWAIT, NULL, NULL) = 11
[pid 27381] sendto(5, "\206\6\0\0\3INSERT INTO menu_router\n   "..., 1674, MSG_DONTWAIT, NULL, 0) = 1674
[pid 27381] poll([{fd=5, events=POLLIN|POLLERR|POLLHUP}], 1, 1471228928) = 1 ([{fd=5, revents=POLLIN}])
[pid 27381] recvfrom(5, "\7\0\0\1\0\1\0\2\0\0\0", 24402, MSG_DONTWAIT, NULL, NULL) = 11
[pid 27381] sendto(5, "!\2\0\0\3INSERT INTO menu_router\n   "..., 549, MSG_DONTWAIT, NULL, 0) = 549
[pid 27381] poll([{fd=5, events=POLLIN|POLLERR|POLLHUP}], 1, 1471228928) = 1 ([{fd=5, revents=POLLIN}])
[pid 27381] recvfrom(5, "\7\0\0\1\0\1\0\2\0\0\0", 24391, MSG_DONTWAIT, NULL, NULL) = 11
[pid 27381] sendto(5, "3\2\0\0\3INSERT INTO menu_router\n   "..., 567, MSG_DONTWAIT, NULL, 0) = 567
[pid 27381] poll([{fd=5, events=POLLIN|POLLERR|POLLHUP}], 1, 1471228928) = 1 ([{fd=5, revents=POLLIN}])
[pid 27381] recvfrom(5, "\7\0\0\1\0\1\0\2\0\0\0", 24380, MSG_DONTWAIT, NULL, NULL) = 11
[pid 27381] sendto(5, "$\2\0\0\3INSERT INTO menu_router\n   "..., 552, MSG_DONTWAIT, NULL, 0) = 552
[pid 27381] poll([{fd=5, events=POLLIN|POLLERR|POLLHUP}], 1, 1471228928) = 1 ([{fd=5, revents=POLLIN}])
[pid 27381] recvfrom(5, "\7\0\0\1\0\1\0\2\0\0\0", 24369, MSG_DONTWAIT, NULL, NULL) = 11
[pid 27381] sendto(5, "*\2\0\0\3INSERT INTO menu_router\n   "..., 558, MSG_DONTWAIT, NULL, 0) = 558
[pid 27381] poll([{fd=5, events=POLLIN|POLLERR|POLLHUP}], 1, 1471228928) = 1 ([{fd=5, revents=POLLIN}])
[pid 27381] recvfrom(5, "\7\0\0\1\0\1\0\2\0\0\0", 24358, MSG_DONTWAIT, NULL, NULL) = 11
[pid 27381] sendto(5, "9\2\0\0\3INSERT INTO menu_router\n   "..., 573, MSG_DONTWAIT, NULL, 0) = 573
[pid 27381] poll([{fd=5, events=POLLIN|POLLERR|POLLHUP}], 1, 1471228928) = 1 ([{fd=5, revents=POLLIN}])
[pid 27381] recvfrom(5, "\7\0\0\1\0\1\0\2\0\0\0", 24347, MSG_DONTWAIT, NULL, NULL) = 11
[pid 27381] sendto(5, "*\2\0\0\3INSERT INTO menu_router\n   "..., 558, MSG_DONTWAIT, NULL, 0) = 558
[pid 27381] poll([{fd=5, events=POLLIN|POLLERR|POLLHUP}], 1, 1471228928) = 1 ([{fd=5, revents=POLLIN}])
[pid 27381] recvfrom(5, "\7\0\0\1\0\1\0\2\0\0\0", 24336, MSG_DONTWAIT, NULL, NULL) = 11
[pid 27381] sendto(5, "-\2\0\0\3INSERT INTO menu_router\n   "..., 561, MSG_DONTWAIT, NULL, 0) = 561
[pid 27381] poll([{fd=5, events=POLLIN|POLLERR|POLLHUP}], 1, 1471228928) = 1 ([{fd=5, revents=POLLIN}])
[pid 27381] recvfrom(5, "\7\0\0\1\0\1\0\2\0\0\0", 24325, MSG_DONTWAIT, NULL, NULL) = 11
[pid 27381] sendto(5, "\33\2\0\0\3INSERT INTO menu_router\n   "..., 543, MSG_DONTWAIT, NULL, 0) = 543
[pid 27381] poll([{fd=5, events=POLLIN|POLLERR|POLLHUP}], 1, 1471228928) = 1 ([{fd=5, revents=POLLIN}])
[pid 27381] recvfrom(5, "\7\0\0\1\0\1\0\2\0\0\0", 24314, MSG_DONTWAIT, NULL, NULL) = 11
[pid 27381] sendto(5, "\6\2\0\0\3INSERT INTO menu_router\n   "..., 522, MSG_DONTWAIT, NULL, 0) = 522
[pid 27381] poll([{fd=5, events=POLLIN|POLLERR|POLLHUP}], 1, 1471228928 <unfinished ...>
```

All of timeouts are reasonable so I don't think that's the issue. Since the server configuration is identical to my other sites, I think it's a code issue, but I'm not sure what in PHP can cause this.

It's Drupal 6.28 and PHP 5.5.20.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `recvfrom/sendto` are just MySQL queries, so it's nothing wrong with it.

Inserting into `menu_router` table indicates that Drupal is rebuilding this table (see: [`menu_rebuild() API`](http://api.drupal.org/menu_rebuild));

> This function will clear and populate the {menu_router} table, add entries
>   to {menu_links} for new router items, and then remove stale items from
>   {menu_links}.

This is either triggered by `menu_rebuild_needed` variable (if set), or by external modules (such as [Devel](http://drupal.org/project/devel)), or simply in your theme settings you've enabled '*Rebuild theme registry on every page.*' option.

Usually rebuilding menu is one-time process on clear cache. If above suggestions won't help, you need to check which module/code exactly calling `menu_rebuild()` (in `includes/menu.inc`) by placing there breakpoint and printing backtrace.

One way of doing (if [Devel](http://drupal.org/project/devel) is present), is using `dd()`, e.g.

```
function menu_rebuild() {
  dd(debug_backtrace()); // Adding temporary debug line.
```

Then check your `/tmp/drupal_debug.txt` file for backtrace details.

Comment: Thanks, this was the problem!